# Checking if text area is blank prior to form submission?

Tags: forms

So I wrote this code so that every time someone clicks the submit button, a javascript
function, called check, will see if the text area is empty.  If it is not, then the form will be submitted.
This is my code.  Why isn't it working?

```
<form method=post name='form_post' id='form_post' action='SUBMITIT.PHP'>
<textarea   id=message name=message class=post onfocus=this.className='post_focus';                                      
placeholder='Share your thoughts'  maxlength=500></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick='check()' id=button name=button>Post</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check() 
{ 
if(!document.textArea.message.value=="") 
{ 
document.forms["form_post"].submit();
}
} 
</script>
```

### Thanks!

EDIT: I finally got it to work.  Here's a template if you are having a similar problem.

```
<!--The form-->
<form action="mypage.php" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<textarea name=myTextArea id=myTextArea>
</textarea>
</form>
<br>
<button onclick='check()'>
Post
</button>

<!--The script that checks-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check(){ 
String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); }; 
var textAreaValue=document.getElementById('myTextArea').value; 
var trimmedTextAreaValue=textAreaValue.trim(); 
if(trimmedTextAreaValue!="") { 
document.forms["myForm"].submit(); 
} 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following woks, and it also wipes unnecessary spaces, the form will only submit when given a character

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check(this)">
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
<script>
function check(form){
    if (form.message.value.trim() == ""){
        return false
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the most simple way to do this, and the advised one.

Comment: doesn't work...and i'm assuming that the action is still the php page i'm submitting it too...;

Comment: i used only an example of form, use yours, and try to just copy and paste everything to see if it works.
If you still needs help, just keep asking xD

Comment: Would this code eliminate spaces?

function check() 
{ 
var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
var message2=trim(message);
if(message2!="")
{ 
document.forms["form_post"].submit();
} 
} 
function trim (myString)     
{     
    return myString.replace(/^s+/g,'').replace(/s+$/g,'')     
}

Comment: Anytime ;D
I made a page with the code working, if you to see, here it is
[link](http://davenorrys.comuv.com/check-textarea-value-prior-submit.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add "required" to the textarea field in HTML.

**Note**: Although the question is quite old, I am adding the answer for the future references.